# Disable Items in drop down list in infopath?

Tags: infopath2010

is there a way to disable items in a dropdown list in infopath?
is it also possible to do so without using code (C#/VB.net&etc)???

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Max

Answer (score 0):

Make the field read-only, then the drop-down control won't fire.